# PHP - Login page/Profile page redirect instead of displaying webpage

Tags: php, redirect

I'm very new to coding in general, and especially PHP so please bear with me. I'm trying to create a login page that redirects to a protected profile page.

validated users will see and be directed to said profile page once they successfully authenticate login.

Okay, so the issue that im running into is that authenticated users are being redirected to home page(index.php) and it will NOT show profile.php page at all

any and all advise is much appreciated!

**CODE FOR PROFILE PAGE**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'connect.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
} 

$query = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE userid=?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([$_SESSION['user']]);
$userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<html>
<head><title>You are logged in!</title></head>
<body>
Thanks so much for visiting,<?php echo $userRow['fname']; ?>
<p><a href="logout.php">Logout Here</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**CODE FOR LOGIN PAGE**

```
<?php
session_start();

if( isset($_SESSION['user'])!="" ){
    header("Location: index.php");
}
include_once 'connect.php';

if ( isset($_POST['sca']) ) {
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $pass = trim($_POST['pass']);
    $password = hash('sha256', $pass);

    $query = "select userid, username, pass from people where 
username=?";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute([$username]);
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if( $count == 1 && $row['pass']==$password ) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row['userid'];
        header("Location: profile.php");
    }
    else {
        $message = "Invalid Login";
    }
    $_SESSION['message'] = $message;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
<style>
body {
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
background-color: #111111;
color: #b2b2b2;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
min-height: 100vh;
flex-direction: column;
margin-top: 50px; 
}

h1 {
color: #AB8BF2;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.menu {
background-color: #212121;
overflow: hidden;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}

.menu a {
display: block;
color: #b2b2b2;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a:hover {
background-color: #444444;
}

.menu a.active {
background-color: #AB8BF2;
color: white;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}

.myDiv {
border: 2px solid #b2b2b2;
background-color: #212121;
padding-left: 40px;
width: 350px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}

form {
margin-top: 20px;
}

label {
display: block;
margin-bottom: 5px;
color: #AB8BF2;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
width: 200px;
padding: 5px;
background-color: #b2b2b2;
color: #111111;
}

input[type="submit"] {
padding: 8px 20px;
background-color: #AB8BF2;
color: #fff;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

a {
color: #AB8BF2;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
color: #AB8BF2;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p><h1>

<?php
if ( isset($message) ) {
    echo $message;
}
?>
</h1></p>
<h1>Login and Leave a Comment!</h1>

<div class="menu">
<a class="active" href="index.php">Home</a>
<div class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropbtn">Table of Contents</a>
<div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#section1">Section 1</a>
  <a href="#section2">Section 2</a>
  <a href="#section3">Section 3</a>
</div>
</div>
<a href="#blog">Blog Posts</a>
<a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
<a href="#subscribe">Subscribe</a>
<a href="login.php">Login</a>
</div>

<div class="myDiv">
<form action="profile.php" method="post">
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>

<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>

<input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>

<p>Don't have an account? <a href="registration.php">Create 
one</a>. 
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[profile page code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLioB.png)
[login page code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfauH.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and I bear with you. However: No screenshots of code. Paste your code, this website is based on text, not screenshots (this will get you more comments, and you may see downvotes [plural]). Perhaps revisit the tour. See [help] for some tips on how you can improve your question (apart from screenshot use).

Comment: `<form action="profile.php"` sends the request to profile.php when the user enters their username and password and submits the form. But there is no code in that page to process that form data. There is some code in login.php which would process some posted form data, but it doesn't quite match the form you've created (in terms of the $_POST values it tries to look for).

Comment: P.S. `if( isset($_SESSION['user'])!="" )` makes no sense. `isset()` returns either true or false. So attempting to compare its output to a string is strange. Just `if( isset($_SESSION['user']))` would make a lot more sense.

Comment: Use [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead of `hash('sha256', $pass)`. You should read [Safe Password Hashing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) for an explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Change `isset($_POST['sca'])` to `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'` and replace form's action with uri to login.php

Comment: There's a little bit more to do as well as this. Look more closely.